# Django 1.4 - extend user model and admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, admin

Let's have 2 models that extends the user model called `Ext1` and `Ext2` declared as follow:

```
class ExtN(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    extra_param = models.xxxField()
```

then I declare in application specific `admin.py` file something like:

```
class ExtNInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ExtN
    can_delete = False
```

in which file do I need to put the following code, in order to see the form to edit both models related to the user?

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (Ext1Inline, Ext2Inline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in the same `admin.py` file

[Extending the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: It doesn't work. The proposed solution works with only one extension, not two as I asked.

Comment: @ipersite I will test it later this day myself